# Possible output after execution of threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently in one my interview i got a question on multi threading which confuse me, so just to clear my concept I am asking this question.

The question was "Is there any possible scenario of execution which can give me output like 7 6 5 or 7 5 6 for following code"

```
public class SampleThread implements Runnable {
 static int x = 4;

 public void run() {
    x++;
    System.out.println(x);
 }
}
```

Now lets say there are 3 Thread instance having same runnable instance as target object as follow

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SampleThread s1=new SampleThread(); 

    Thread t1=new Thread(s1);
    Thread t2=new Thread(s1);
    Thread t3=new Thread(s1);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
 }}
```

Comment: Why this question has been down voted?I have given clear question description and it is quite useful to understand threads concept.So please instead of down voting try to give correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remember that the threads are running concurrently rather that one after another.

Since they're writing and reading a shared variable without synchronization of any kind, memory consistency errors are likely to occur. In this case, all you can say for sure is that an increment happens before the print operation in each thread (but not always immediately before, since the other threads might be reading or writing as well). Threads reading values simultaneously, making a change based in an outdated value, reading after another thread changed the value are the kind of situations that could lead to outputs like 765 or 766.

Take a look at Oracle's documentation regarding concurrency and Memory consistency, it's very detailed: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility